# In Bayesian Linear Regression, do I need to take multiple samples of the Posterior for prediction?

Tags: bayesian, sampling

Given $$\begin {align} 
\beta&\sim\mathcal N(1.5,1)\\
y&\sim\mathcal N(\beta x,5.5)
\end{align}
$$I have 10,000 samples
from the posterior $\beta_S\sim P(\beta|x)$

Is it enough to get the prediction posterior samples by computing $\hat \mu_s=\beta_s x$ for $s=1\cdots10,000$?

And getting a **Single** sample with dimension $(10000,1)$ from $
\mathcal N(\hat\mu,5.5)
$?

---

Or do I still need to take N samples of the above and get a sample dimension $(N,10000,1)$?

I need the prediction distribution samples and I don't know how to properly get the posterior predictive samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the posterior predictive for $y$, which will be given as $p(y^{rep}|y)=\int p(y^{rep}|\beta,y)p(\beta|y)=\int p(y^{rep}|\beta)p(\beta|y)$. This suggests the following procedure for generating samples from the posterior predictive.

1. Draw from your posterior of $\beta_s\sim p(\beta|y)$
2. From each of your sampled $\beta_s$ draw $y|\beta_s\sim N(\beta_s x,5.5)$.

Comment: In step 2, how many samples $y|\beta_s$ for a single sampled $\beta_s$? Is one sample sufficient or do I take M samples and get the mean

Comment: One sample is sufficient in step 2 for each $\beta_s$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!